# Mturk External Survey Code

Tags: validation, amazon-web-services, survey, mechanicalturk

I am trying to link up Mturk to my external Website

I am using the external survey Hit on the GUI requester page

I know that I need to generate the code myself, but I do not know how the code is validated.

In what form or fashion do I, or the Amazon site validate this code? and how do I implement this.

For example: A person gets a code from my website, and pastes it into the box of their amazon hit on the amazon website. Who is that code validated by? and if amazon how to I tell them which codes have been generated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do it yourself. you will find the code that the worker enters on the HIT page in your results file. Than you compare the results file with the list of codes you generated, and approve the correct codes.

Comment: Thank you! I would vote you up but i dont have the rep yet apparently! -_-

Answer (score 1):

A method is described [on my blog](https://tylerburleigh.com/mturk/efficient-method-for-validating-lots-of-survey-codes/) which is ideal for surveys with lots of participants. Basically, you export the data from both your survey and Mechanical Turk, then you put the code columns side-by-side for comparison, and then you use a formula that takes each row of one column of codes and performs a lookup in the other column of codes. For example, you could use a COUNTIF formula in Excel, which returns a 1 if there is a single match, and a 0 otherwise.